# SignaturePad isn't so smooth?

Tags: javascript, signaturepad

I have tried looking for a signature pad to allow signature drawing in my website,

The SignaturePads that I looked at are these:

- https://github.com/szimek/signature_pad (Demo: http://szimek.github.io/signature_pad/)
- https://github.com/ezl/signature-pad (Demo: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Smooth-Signature-Pad-Plugin-with-jQuery-Html5-Canvas/examples/)

In the past I have used Szimek signature pad and everything works fine but when comparing the demo to the second demo of Ezl signature pad the smoothness of Ezl supersedes Szimek in the smoothness.

Ezl Signature Pad:

[image: Ezl Signature Pad]

Szimek Signature Pad:
[image: Szimek Signature Pad]

I have tried modifying the throttling setting of the Szimek plugin and also in general I prefer using the Szimek plugin because there is better support, contributions and community to it.

Does anyone knows why do I get such a bad quality in comparison to the Ezl plugin?